# Json методы, как получить информацию из deviations

Tags: java, json, api, url

у меня есть задание, в одной части из которого я должен получить сообщение с сайта о возможной задержке поезда.

```
String adress2 = "http://api.sl.se/api2/deviations.json?key=d3fa46ed7ddf4af7a5ef18fd353f0088&transportMode=metro&lineNumber=10&siteId=9161&fromDate=2018-05-24&toDate=2018-05-25";

    try {
        URL v = new URL(adress2);
        URLConnection connection = v.openConnection();

        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
        int code = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(code != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            throw new MalformedURLException();
        }

        InputStream instream = connection.getInputStream();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(instream);

        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String input = in.nextLine();
            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(input);

            //Проблема на строке ниже

            JSONObject response = result.getJSONObject("ResponseData");
            String message = response.getString("Details");


        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Felaktig adress");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Filen kunde inte läsas in");
    }
```

ResponseData имеет тип deviations, Details имеет тип стринг. Я получаю ошибку:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["ResponseData"] is not a JSONObject.

Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Comment: https://www.trafiklab.se/node/12605/documentation здесь информация по этому API, сверху справа переключатель языка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!result.isNull("ResponseData"))
    JSONObject response = result.getJSONObject("ResponseData");
else
    System.err.println("Error: " + result.getString("Message"));
```